# how to get 2 div's text to align along the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a contact page and would like to have 2 columns, one with a label (e.g. facebook, twitter) and one with the actual details. The thing is I want the two lines (which have text of different size) to both align along the bottom edge.

It's probably easier if I show you: http://goonbee.com/contact

At the moment, the label and details are vertically aligned along the centre. How can I make them align along the bottom?

My CSS is:

```
#contactbox {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

#contactboxlabels {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #c9c9c9;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#contactboxdetails {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #545454;
    line-height: 42px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="contactbox">
    <div id="contactboxlabels">
        <span>email<br />twitter<br />facebook<br />phone</span>
    </div>

    <div id="contactboxdetails">
        <span><a href="mailto:x@x.com">x@x.com</a><br /><a href="http://twitter.com/goonbee">@goonbee</a><br /><a href="http://facebook.com/goonbee">facebook.com/goonbee</a><br /><a href="tel:+44000000">+44 000000</a></span>
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your markup is not very semantic. The keys belong with their values, they are not an independent column. This would be the most semantic, minimal markup:

```
<dl>
  <dt>email</dt>    <dd>touch@goonbee.com</dd>
  <dt>twitter</dt>  <dd>@goonbee</dd>
  <dt>facebook</dt> <dd>facebook.com/goonbee</dd>
  <dt>phone</dt>    <dd>+44 7825 163256</dd>
</dl>
```

For styling this, the only drawback is that you need to set the width of your `dt` "column" explicitly in order to get them to line up:

```
dl { font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

/* column layout */
dt {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 4.25em; /* needs to be set for longest item */
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}

dd {
  overflow: hidden; /* creates an implicit column from remaining space */
}
```

You can then adjust `line-height` on the `dt` and add `padding-top` to keep the heights the same and match up the baselines:

```
/* typography */
dt {
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 29px; /* 42 - padding-top */
  padding-top: 13px; /* ceil( (42 - font-size) / 2 ) */
  color: #c9c9c9;
  text-align: right;
}

dd {
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 42px;
  color: #545454;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to set the width of the left column and have it align based on the longest element, like a table column, then use a table! This would give you better control over the `vertical-align` as well. I don't think a table would be inappropriate here, especially if you mark up the left column as `th` headers.

Comment: I'm not so sure a definition list would be the "most semantic" markup here -- you're not actually defining what a Facebook or a Twitter is, are you? This is a series of heading/value pairings, and that, folks, is a table. Oddly enough, tables allow for bottom-alignment in cells. It may be the height of evil to use tables arbitrarily for layout, but it's just as bad to avoid tables when they best represent the data structure you're trying to portray.

Comment: I tend to agree that I would probably go with a table here as well, but the heading-value pattern _is_ what definition lists are meant for. Yes, you _are_ defining the lookup value for Facebook, Twitter, etc. I wouldn't call it wrong; it _is_ semantic that way too. (Plus, multiple `dd` elements such as extra email addresses under one `dt` would be legal too: that's not the case with a table, where you either need to add a column for the second value, or a list inside the cell to keep it "semantic".)

Answer (score 2):

at the moment you have the labels in one container and the values in another. this will make it harder to work with and is also not semantic and meaningful.

put each label and value in its own container. you'll end up with 4 pairs of label/value.

give the container `position:relative;` and then use `position:absolute;` for both the label and value. as long as the bottom for both is `0` then they should both be aligned along the bottom edge.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 75px; text-align: right; padding-right: 10px; padding-top:15px;">email</div>
    <div><a href="mailto:touch@goonbee.com">touch@goonbee.com</a></div>
</div>
```

or...

```
<div>
    <span style="vertical-align: bottom; padding-right: 10px;">email</span>
    <a href="mailto:touch@goonbee.com">touch@goonbee.com</a>
</div>
```